# How to click disabled option menu item in Toolbar android?

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I have two option items in a Toolbar. When one item is clicked, that item will be enabled. Then another item must be disabled. But, once the item was disabled I can't fire click event anymore on that item. Is there anyway that I can click on the disable item?

Thank you

[image]

I did like this but its not working anymore

```
 MenuItem tureMenuItem;
 MenuItem dingMenuItem

 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
   getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lore_fragment, menu);
   tureMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_ture);
   dingMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_ding);
   tureMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
   dingMenuItem.setEnabled(false);


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_ding:
            tureMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
            dingMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_ture:
            tureMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            dingMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using setEnabled() will work. manage with your conditions.

you must be doing some action on those menu items right. You can enable the other item at the end of action.since you have not posted I have only option. Using Handler.PostDelayed.

```
 boolean isMenuEnabled;
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings) {

                    this.isMenuEnabled = true;

                    tureMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                    dingMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
             handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                    return true;
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.action_settings1) {

                this.isMenuEnabled = true;

                tureMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
                dingMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                return true;
            }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

remove the callbacks

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

runnable  with delay

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isMenuEnabled){
                tureMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                dingMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                isMenuEnabled=false;
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: please post what actually you are doing when you have clicked on menu item

Comment: Actually I am changing the content according to the option menu item

Comment: Then enable the menu item at the end of that task. cant you do that?

Comment: there is two menu item. One menu item has to be disabled all the time. If I select the 1st menu item, second menu item must disable and load first menu content and Vice versa.But the problem here is I can't click on the disabled menu. So  I think this doesn't work. I did use custom menu layout. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below example code to `disable` and `enable` menu item vice-versa.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);      
     if(menu.getItem(0))
        {
        menu.getItem(0).setEnable(false);
        menu.getItem(1).setEnable(true); 
        }
     else if(menu.getItem(1))
       {
        menu.getItem(1).setEnable(false);
        menu.getItem(0).setEnable(true); 
       }        

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```